# Where are the water damage indicators on a G2?

Tags: hardware, htc-desire-z

I got a G2 from eBay and it looks pretty nice.  I'm just inspecting to make sure everything is good before I start using it.  The battery has a white water damage indicator, which is good, but the battery could have been replaced.  Are there other indicators?  Where?

[image: white rectangle on battery]
[image: white dot under battery]
[image: scary pink and white]
[image: VOID sticker]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this thread](http://forums.t-mobile.com/t5/T-Mobile-Touch-Pro2/Water-damage-indicators/td-p/200480) on the T-Mobile forums there are a few people talking about water damage indicators.  The OP mentions this:

> When I remove the back of the phone and the screen is face-down on a table, the triangle is just above the left side of the micro SD card door.  It's visible even with the battery left in place.

...which another person confirms is a water damage indicator.

If you don't see any pink triangles I think you're in good shape.

**Edit:** Does your phone look like this with the battery out?  Because it looks to me like that white circle near the bottom right is the only water sensor on the body of the phone itself.
[image: G2]

Comment: I don't see anything white or pink anywhere near the micro SD slot (which is *not* visible with the battery left in place).  There is a white rectangle on the bottom of the battery near the contacts, a white circle on the phone underneath the battery, a white hemisphere with a pink part on it inside one of the battery cover holes, and a small black circle with white "VOID" on it, with a hole in it.

Comment: I just edited my post, take a look and let me know if this is relevant at all.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that, and I see the white circle.  The white/pink thing I see is inside the hole to the left of the FCC symbol, not visible at the angle your picture is taken at.

Comment: I think it would be a little odd if they put a water sensor inside the chassis in such a way, so I don't think the pink you see is a triggered moisture sensor.  Then again, I don't own a G2 and have never seen one in person.

Comment: I added pictures to my question.

Answer (score 3):

See the white circle right above the battery contacts? It's in the picture. That is the phone's water damage indicator. How do I know? Because mine is bright red. Trust me, there'd be no doubt...